# Prevent SC_METHOD from executing without event/trigger

Tags: c++, systemc

My method `fsm1` executes once even without event and therefore `id1_cmd.read()` and `id1_value.read()` contain 0 and not the correct values.

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Method:  control::fsm1() 
//  Parameter: None
//  @Sensitivity: ID_1_cmd (unsigned int)
//------------------------------------------------------------------
void control::fsm1() {
   cout << id1_cmd.read() << endl;
   cout << id1_value.read() << endl;

}

//------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Method: Constructor
//------------------------------------------------------------------
SC_CTOR(control) {
    SC_METHOD(fsm1);
    sensitive << id1_cmd;
}
```

Exists there a way to prevent it from executing once or do i have to handle that case always in my methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `dont_initialize` method see the [Language Reference Manual](https://paginas.fe.up.pt/~ee07166/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=1666-2011.pdf)

```
SC_CTOR(control) {
    SC_METHOD(fsm1);
    sensitive << id1_cmd;
    dont_initialize();
}
```